# Can you force a smaller instance in AWS Cloudsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

My AWS Cloudsearch instance has 32 million small records, and auto-scaled up to search.m3.2xlarge.  Using the AWS console, this was reset to search.m3.medium and reindexed.  Performance was slower, but surprisingly good, and more than sufficient for the use case.

A week later, it had auto-scaled back up search.m3.2xlarge without any change to the console settings. No new data was added, and fewer than 10 searches had been performed.

Question:  How do I force it to remain at the smaller search.m3.medium instance type?